# What are the advantages of eutectic solvents over aqueous solutions for electroplating?

Tags: solvents, eutectic, electroplating

I'm trying to electrically strip lead contamination from aluminum.

[This answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/10359/5354) suggests using a deep eutectic solvent (DES) as the conducting liquid for plating the lead onto a copper cathode.  But now that I'm thinking about it I can't see why.  Is a DES more conductive?  More inert with respect to (these) metals?

What advantage does a DES have over conductive aqueous solutions for electroplating?